# How do I recursively put only certain file types from a linux server using ncftp

Tags: ftp

I want to upload only .mp3 files from my vps to a remote ftp. So, i tried out following code. But it does not seems to do the job.

```
ncftpput  -R -v -u "username" -p "password" ftp.ftpsite.com /public_html /dir/*.mp3
```

Any method to do this task? Please note that the remote ftp does not support ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Start with collecting a list of files you want to transfer, e.g.

```
find Music/ -name '*.mp3' > my.list
```

Then find a suitable command e.g.

```
cat my.list | ftp -
```

to use that file list with your favourite ftp client.